# Printing in Word 2010 without the print preview

Tags: microsoft-word, printing

I would like to print a Word 2010 document without going into the Print Preview.  How do I do this?

Comment: The keyboard shortcut for this seems to be CTRL+P, Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or `File -- Print` will do a `Print Preview And Print`

The functionality that you are looking for is hidden in the QAT (Quick Access Toolbar) See the below screenshot

[image]